# csv export failing when executing jupyter notebook from command line

Tags: python, command-line, jupyter-notebook

I have a jupyter notebook that i am executing from command line using

```
jupyter run Anomaly.ipynb
```

now in my notebook i am exporting the dataframe as csv

```
df.to_csv('exceptions.csv')
```

Query- when I run the notebook from browser it exports the csv file in the folder but when I run the notebook from command line it does not exports the file

Comment: it may run code in different folder then you expect - first try `/full/path/to/exceptions.csv`. OR you should check `Current Working Directory` - `print( os.getcwd() )`

Comment: I tried with the complete path as well.. But no luck

Comment: don't you get any error message when you run it? Do you use `try/except`? Maybe it hides error. You could use `print()` to display some information to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing. Without extra information we have no idea what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

changed my execution command to and it worked

```
runipy Anomaly.ipynb
```